# getting error for setArray while using preparedstatement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Please consider the following code:

```
 List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 ids.add(SelectQueueRS.getInt("DTSId_int"));

 // SelectQueueRS is a ResultSet object


 PreparedStatement updateOriginal = connRemote.prepareStatement(

  "UPDATE test.contactqueue SET DTSStatusType_ti = 3, Queued_DialerIP_vch = ?" +
  "WHERE DTSId_int IN (?)"); 

  updateOriginal.setString(1, ip);
  updateOriginal.setArray(connRemote.createArrayOf("string", ids.toArray()));
  updateOriginal.executeUpdate;
```

I am getting following errors on the following lines:

On the Line :  `updateOriginal.setArray(connRemote.createArrayOf("string", ids.toArray()));`

[image]

AND on line :`updateOriginal.executeUpdate;`

Error says : `not a statement`

Please advise how can I correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parameter index in `updateOriginal.setArray`, it should be `updateOriginal.setArray(2, connRemote.createArrayOf("string", ids.toArray()));`

Another issue is, that You want to create an array of database string type, where your statement expects it to be array of numeric type - but this might be irrelevant

Second error is caused by missing brackets...it should be `updateOriginal.executeUpdate();`

Comment: Thanks ,that worked !! Was missing `()` in second error